# 1. The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, yaml, cloud, aws-cloudformation

I want to provision a Ec2 where I have to bootstrap the tomcat server  by cfn. when i upload the template I got this  bellow error

```
The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterCombination; Request ID: dce48dfe-24dc-48a8-a875-5b9148e8f864; Proxy: null)
```

```
    
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Description: This Template Create an EC2 in private subnet.

Parameters: 
  KeyName:
    Description: Name of an existing EC2 KeyPair to enable SSH access to the instance
    Type: String
    Default: demo

  VPCId:
    Description: VpcId of your existing Virtual Private Cloud (VPC)
    Type: String
    Default: vpc-0c9a732125ac08541 

  PrivateSubnetId:
    Description: SubnetId of an existing subnet (for the primary network in your Virtual Private Cloud VPC)
    Type: String
    Default: subnet-062e25e97c1645a2b

Resources:
  TomcatInstance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'  
    Properties:
      KeyName: !Ref KeyName
      SecurityGroups:
        - !Ref TomcatSecurityGroup
        - !Ref TomcatCustomTCPSecurityGroup
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:    
          #!/bin/bash
          sudo yum install java -y
          req_tom_ver= 10.0.27
          tom_m_v=$(echo $req_tom_ver|cut -c 1,2)
          URL= https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-${tom_m_v}/v${req_tom_ver}/bin/apache-tomcat-${req_tom_ver}.tar.gz
          wget $URL
          sudo tar -xvzf apache-tomcat-${req_tom_ver}.tar.gz
          sudo mv apache-tomcat-${req_tom_ver} tomcat${tom_m_v}
          sudo rm -rf apache-tomcat-${req_tom_ver}.tar.gz
          sudo chmod 700 /tomcat${tom_m_v}/bin/*.sh
          cd /tomcat${tom_m_v}/bin
          sudo ./startup.sh
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-1a
      ImageId: ami-0aa7d40eeae50c9a9
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: !Ref PrivateSubnetId
      

  TomcatSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPCId
      GroupDescription: Enable SSH access via port 22
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '22'
          ToPort: '22'
          CidrIp:  0.0.0.0/0

  TomcatCustomTCPSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      VpcId: !Ref VPCId
      GroupDescription: Enable tomcat access via port 8080
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: '8080'
          ToPort: '8080'
          CidrIp:  0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Please consult the documentation before posting questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [SecurityGroupIds](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroupids), instead of `SecurityGroups`.